# Voice panning in Agora is all-or-nothing at very small "pan" values, and drastically lowers volume

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

I'm using the Agora SDK in Unity to enable players to voice chat with each other, and using [SetRemoteVoicePosition(uid, pan, gain)](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/flutter/v4.0.1/rtc_engine/RtcEngine/setRemoteVoicePosition.html) to make the voices sound like they're coming from their location in world. I've outputted the value I'm feeding in as "pan" and it's within the -1.0 to 1.0 range defined in the docs. But I've noticed some odd behavior: If "pan" is -0.00999 to 0.00999, it treats the pan as "perfectly centered"; but the instant it hits -0.01 or 0.01, it IMMEDIATELY slams all the way to the left or right channel, which is accompanied by a sudden drop in volume because it's suddenly lost one of the channels.

The problem here is the suddenness of it. I have no apparent way for the voice to be at 100% in the right channel and 85% in the left channel, for example; it's either 100% in both, or 0% in one or the other, nothing in between.

Here's the full function. (The distance calculation works properly, and when I uncomment the Debug.Log, the pan values are what I would expect to see: -1 for someone directly to the left, 1 for someone directly to the right, and smoothly moving in between them as expected.)

```
        public void SetSpeakerPosition(uint uid, Vector3 worldPosition)
        {
            Vector3 localPosition = transform.InverseTransformPoint(worldPosition);
            float distanceToSpeaker = localPosition.magnitude;
            float gain = GetEmitterVolume(distanceToSpeaker) * 100f * VTWConfigManager.config.voiceChatVolume * dynamicVolumeMultiplier;
            float pan = 0f;
            if (VTWConfigManager.config.voiceChatPanningActive) 
                pan = Mathf.Lerp(
                    0f, 
                    Vector3.Dot(localPosition.normalized, Vector3.right),
                    panFactorByRange.Evaluate(distanceToSpeaker / maxRange));
            //Debug.Log($"Pan for {uid} is {pan} for x-pos {localPosition.normalized.x}; volume is {gain}");
            audioEffects.SetRemoteVoicePosition(uid, pan, gain);
        }
```

During initialization and before joining the room, I also call `mRtcEngine.EnableSoundPositionIndication(true);` as mentioned in the above-linked doc.

Comment: Have you tried hardcoding it? I mean are you sure the `pan` has the expected values?

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% certain that `pan` has the values, that's exactly why I logged its value here, and it's how I found the correlation with 0.0099999 to 0.01 being the threshold for "center" to "all the way right". And as you can see there's no other logic occurring on `pan` in between the log and calling this function.

Comment: I encourage you to use the ticket system from your account console to get Agora support on this.